# Is giving Debit card number to freelancer.com secure?

Tags: freelance-websites, payment-terms

I am new to work as a freelancer online. Recently I found a website freelancer.co.in. I want to work as a freelancer on it. But it is asking my Debit card number. I am afraid to give the details of my credit card. I am afraid that they could deduct money from my account. I am thinking to make first nill balance in the account. I want to earn money not to spend. Getting it straight forward, I want to ask,

> - Would any money be deducted from my bank account if I give my Debit card number or internet banking details to that website?

Comment: This sounds more like you are asking about a debt card than a credit card. Credit cards don't allow merchants to "deduct money" from any account. While debit and credit cards can often be used similarly, they **are not** the same thing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about freelancing, but how to use someone else's site.  Go ask *there*

Answer (score 1):

It's usually safe unless they are hacked.

So I would rather get a new card with limited withdraw money (or virtual credit card as someone pointed out), and use that card, instead of my real card.

Others use gift cards for the same purpose.